# Get anchors to fill remaining area in the parent

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a QML component called MyComponent and I have the following instantiations:

```
MyComponent {
    id: rightComponent

    SettingsScreenHeader {
        id: settingsHeader
    }

    SettingsScreen {
        id: settingsScreen
    }

    StackView {
        id: settingsStack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: settingsScreen
    }
}
```

`SettingsScreenHeader` and `SettingsScreen` are two other components. At the moment when I do `anchors.fill: parent` in the `StackView` object, it takes all the space and the header object gets obscured. Is there a way to tell it to fill all the remaining space in the parent?

Comment: Do you want them placed as a column?

Comment: I guess but I do not want the Column object as I find it becomes very difficult to then add MouseArea to it and I never know if I will need that in the future.

Comment: Actually I just tried the Column control now and even with my current component it has issues with the anchors and stuff due to dynamic text and image assignments...

Comment: @Luca the thing is you should choose the right tool for the right job: forcing anchoring on `Column` is a bad idea since it places `Item`s by itself. Depending on your needs you can use positioners or layouts. For text `Column` it's hardly an issue. I would say that positioners (`Column`, `Row` ..) are actually the best for growing `Item`s with test. My two cents, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ColumnLayout`:

```
MyComponent {
    id: rightComponent

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        SettingsScreenHeader {
            id: settingsHeader
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        SettingsScreen {
            id: settingsScreen
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        StackView {
            id: settingsStack
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            initialItem: settingsScreen
        }
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) for further details.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I did not know you had Layout items in QML. I only learnt about anchors today as well!